# Forms built with CodeIgniter not working

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I am having trouble working with forms created using codeigniter. I have tried number of ways to render a form on the webpage. But am unsuccessful at different points.

I am looking to render this

I tried to render a form with code:

```
<?php $this -> load -> helper('form');
    $formattr = array('id="form1"'); 
    form_open('registerUsr', $formattr);?>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Registration Form</legend>
            <p class="first">
                <label for="firstName">First Name: </label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="firstName" size="20" value="<?php echo set_value('first_name'); ?>" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
        <p class="submit"><button type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

I tried to create it using codeigniter functions

```
<?php echo form_open('registerUsr'); 
  echo form_input('$data'); 
  echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit'); 
  echo form_close();?>
```

I have tried hybrid variety using mix of html tags and helper class functions.

But in all the ways, on final render of the form on web page `<form class=“form1”>` tags are missing. And also instead of index.php/registerUsr, it is going into index.php/searchUniv page. (I have Checked routes config file. It is correctly pointed)

Any suggestions / ideas appreciated.

TIA :)

Update: Here is the controller and routes file

```
public function registration() {
        $this -> template -> title -> set('Register');
        $this -> template -> _content -> view('register_index', $overwrite = TRUE);
        $this -> template -> _sidebar -> view('gen_sidebar', $overwrite = TRUE);
        $this -> template -> publish();
    }

public function registerUsr(){
        $this -> template -> title -> set('Register');
        $searchItem = $this -> input -> post('form1');
        $this -> template -> publish();
    }
}
```

register_index.php is the code thats in the question which now looks okay.

```
$route['searchUniv']="sglobal/searchUniv";
$route['registration']="sglobal/registration";
$route['registerUsr']="sglobal/registerUsr";
```

template is the custom library i wrote which is working absolutely fine in all other pages. This application is in final stages, so I can say with 95% confidence, template is working okay. Also I am looking at the source of final rendered page and its exactly whats wanted. So, Can we look into any configurations before pointing at template.

Now the final render looks like:

```
<form action="http://localhost/univapp/index.php/registerUsr" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="form1" class="form1">
```

but on submit its going to `http://localhost/univapp/index.php/searchUniv`

JUST FYI, I also have another search form on the same page (far away div, different id, different name, different class) which uses POST that points to index.php/searchUniv. Is there any problem because of that?

Comment: maybe if you indented your code properly you would see the error more easily...

Comment: @hugo_leonardo instead of leaving such comments you can always edit the post indenting the code by yourself

Comment: @AshokBommisetti have you tried using plain html? I think the problem might be unrelated to this code.

Comment: @Vlakarados just to clarify, my comment was just a sincere tip, no harm intended. he won't have me to indent his code at home every time...

Comment: @hugo_leonardo at some point when he'll be used to SO he will do it himself, but right now it was better to edit yourself

Comment: The array passed to form_open should be Key => Value pairs, You may not through array(id="form1") instead give it something like array('id' => 'form1'); & don't forget that this function returns the output so in order to make it visible you'll have to use echo

Comment: echo form_open('registerUsr', array('id' => 'form1'));

Comment: Hi.. Sorry for mess up there.. I indented it properly on my machine.. on copying here.. It didnt show up properly.. Next, I tried just HTML.. I mean <form method="" id=""></form> in view file and loaded it.. Output still missed the tags.

Comment: @ahmad thats one mistake..I rectified.. Still form tag not shown up...

Comment: @ahmad I have updated the question. Now form tag is fixed. Earlier, I had a caching mechanism which prevented changes in the page from immediately being displayed. Turned it off. With the mistake you pointed, Form is coming. But its not picking the right destination. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid using Codeigniter helpers if they are not needed, html renders faster than php.  All that's required from the form helper is form_open() as this adds the csrf token.
There also appears to be some typo's in your code!

**Checklist:**

***application/config/config.php***

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.mysite.com/'; //I suspect this is your problem with routing
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
```

***application/config/routes.php***

```
$route['register']  = 'controller/get_method'; //form
$route['register/post'] = 'controller/post_method'; //validation
```

***views/registerUsr.php***

```
<?php if( validation_errors() ) : ?>
  <p class=error>Please Correct the Errors below</p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?=form_open('register/post', array('id'=>'', 'class'=>''))?>

<fieldset>
    <legend></legend>
    <label for="firstname">
        <span class=required>*</span>
        First Name
        <small class=helper>Enter your First Name</small>
    </label>
    <input type=text id=firstname name=firstname value="<?=set_value('firstname')?>"/>
    <?=form_error('firstname')?>

    <button type=submit>Submit</button>
</fieldset>

<?=form_close()?>
```

Comment: Looks good, but I would advise against using the short-hand php echo, it's generally a bad practice & not supported everywhere.

Comment: Aye, force of habit to mirror my config

Comment: @Philip: Changed my config to $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE; Triple Checked my routes to be sure;have edited my file to include form_open attributes. Cant I use post to capture data from the form? I have a search bar that is rendered in the same page which uses POST and its working fine.

Comment: update the question with your controller & url you're accessing to see what's wrong, most examples given are perfectly OK.

Comment: @Philip: I found the form error to be in my caching mechanism.. Corrected code didnt take effect bcoz of it so far.. Now I have form thats rendered with form tag with action pointed to index.php/registerUsr but still is going to index.php/searchUniv. BTW, The search bar on the top of the page thats using the other POST is pointed to searchUniv. I have also triple checked their id and names. Nothing in common between them

Comment: You could use $_POST but the data would need to be filtered and sanitized manually. $this->input->post() takes care of most of this for you. EDit: why are you caching forms? You only want to cache output data. Turn caching off for that controller

Comment: @Philip I had deployed a caching mechanism for all pages. Testing it out too. Which is I could not see immediate changes of page render (form render). I turned it off and I could see the change. Now only problem remained is wrong redirection.

Comment: $config['base_url'] points to 'http://localhost/univapp/', like I suggested in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your first example does not echo `form_open()`. Try adding echo before the function call.

```
<?php $this -> load -> helper('form');
    $formattr = array('id="form1"'); 
    echo form_open('registerUsr', $formattr);?>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Registration Form</legend>
            <p class="first">
                <label for="firstName">First Name: </label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="firstName" size="20" value="<?php echo set_value('first_name'); ?>" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
        <p class="submit"><button type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

A form by default will also submit to the current page, likely the reason it is being directed to index.php/searchUniv.

Comment: I did add echo. Now also form tag is not there in source. But here is the point, page is loaded from index.php -> /registration, got to post to /registerUsr but is redirecting to /searchUniv. In the rendered page, there is no reference to searchUniv. In the routes file, its properly routed to /registerUsr.

Comment: Any insight is appreciated

Comment: Can you post your controller?

Comment: I have updated the question. Now form tag is fixed. Earlier, I had a caching mechanism which prevented changes in the page from immediately being displayed. Turned it off. With the mistake you pointed, Form is coming properly. But its not picking the right destination. Any suggestions? Posted routes, controller and everything in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the error. I was looking at 'view source' option to find out how the page was rendering and what data is presented. But a look with DOM inspector (Inspect Element) output showed me that the DOM is still not considering the form tag. It removed it as a part of the correction the DOM performed on the invalid HTML populated by PHP.

Any attribute that's given as `<input name=...  .... />` is being populated as `<input name=... .... >` thus leaving a lot of open tags. Once every tag that says `<  />` in template is changed `<> </>`, it started working.

In brief, the code is ran through validator and everything is fine now.

Thanks for all of your help!